# Back and forth arrows inclined at different angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to draw back and forth arrows (not two-way arrows) inclined at different angles as shown in the figure below. The gray points that don't have to be displayed in the figure are used for positioning.

```
\documentclass[UTF8,fontset=windows]{ctexart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\newcommand\lrreturn[3][]{%left right 
\draw[->,#1]($(#2.0)+(0,2pt)$)--($(#3.180)+(0,2pt)$);
\draw[<-,#1]($(#2.0)+(0,-2pt)$)--($(#3.180)+(0,-2pt)$);
}
\newcommand\udreturn[3][]{%up down 
\draw[->,#1]($(#2.-90)+(2pt,0)$)--($(#3.90)+(2pt,0)$);
\draw[<-,#1]($(#2.-90)+(-2pt,0)$)--($(#3.90)+(-2pt,0)$);
}
\begin{document}
\tikz[node distance=1.5em and 2em,line width=1pt,>=latex]{
\node[red,font=\bfseries] (a) {Center};

\node[right=of a,blue] (b) {0};

\node[below=of a,blue] (c) {$-\pi/2$};


\lrreturn[red]ab
\udreturn[red]ac

}

\tikz{
\node[draw] (o) at (0,0) {Center};
\foreach \i in {0,30,...,180} {
\node[draw] (x\i) at (\i:2) {\i};
\draw[latex-latex] (o) to (x\i);
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works if the nodes are not drawn (or if the nodes are circular). Also, it only works with straight lines.

The usage is `\draw[twoway] (A) to (B);` to draw the back-and-forth arrows between coordinates (A) and (B).

[image]

Basically, a vector perpendicular to the given line is calculated and then two arrows are drawn using `pathreplacing` a short perpendicular distance from the original. The distance between the arrows is controlled globally with `\arsp`.

```
\documentclass[UTF8,fontset=windows]{ctexart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\arsp}{.8mm}

\tikzset{
    twoway/.style={
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            lineto code={
                \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst); \pgfgetlastxy{\a}{\b};
                \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y};
                \coordinate (uu) at ($(0,0)!.5*\arsp!(\b-\y,\x-\a)$);
                \draw[-latex]($(\a,\b)+(uu)$) to ($(\x,\y)+(uu)$);
                \draw[latex-]($(\a,\b)-(uu)$) to ($(\x,\y)-(uu)$);
            }
        }, decorate
    } 
}

\begin{document}

\tikz{
\node[draw,circle] (o) at (0,0) {Center};
\foreach \i in {0,30,...,180} {
    \node[draw,circle] (x\i) at (\i:2) {\i};
    \draw[twoway] (o) to (x\i);
}}

\end{document}
```